# Proof verification - proving $\sup(\frac{1}{A})=\frac{1}{\inf(A)}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a set which is bounded below, and with inf($S$)$>0$. Define $T=\{\frac{1}{x}:x\in S\}$. Prove that $T$ is bounded with $\sup(T)
=\frac{1}{\inf(S)}$.

My 'solution' : Suppose $\inf(S)=a$. Then for all $x\in S$ we have that $a\leq x$, and so $\frac{1}{a}\geq\frac{1}{x}$. As such $\frac{1}{a}$ is an upper bound for $T$.

Now suppose there is a smaller upper bound for $T$, say $\frac{1}{s}:s\in S$. Then we have $\frac{1}{a}\geq\frac{1}{s}\geq\frac{1}{x}$. As such $a\leq s\leq x$, meaning $a$ is not the GREATEST lower bound for $s$, a contradiction. Therefore $\sup(S)=\frac{1}{\sup(T)}$ as required.

Comment: Why do you take $s\in S$?

Comment: I thought that since 1/S is the set T we need s in S?

Comment: No. If you take it like this, you are somehow already assuming that $T$ has a maximum element, which is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite agree with the first part : if $x \in S$ then $a \le x$ so $\frac1x \le \frac1a$ and $\frac1a$ is an upper bound. So far so good.

So suppose $b$ is any upper bound for $T$ (it has to be the smallest among all *real number* candidates not just those from $T$!). It follows that if $x \in S$, $\frac1x$ is in $T$ so $\frac1x \le b$ and so $x \ge \frac1b$ so that $\frac1b$ is a lower bound for $S$ and so $\frac1b \le a$ as $a=\inf(S)$ is the *largest* lower bound for $S$. It follows then that $\frac1a \le b$ and indeed $\frac1a$ is the smallest lower bound for $T$.